# How to know that flash is completed using javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, flash, charts, export-to-pdf

I am doing below actions on button click in sequence,  using javascript.

1. Generating Flash chart
2. Making image of generated flash chart
3. Exporting generated image in to PDF

Everything is dynamic. chart is generated using Open flash chart  and are dynamic using php Mysql

All working fine. Problem here is that is takes some time to generate flash chart. So it's creating  a blank image or image in middle form flash file exporting it to PDF.

It should proceed for generating image once flash is completed.

How can I get that flash has completed ?

How to synchronize these events ?

Comment: do you have access to the flash's source code? you could call a javascript function from flash once the action is completed

Comment: No. and I don't want to do anything there

Comment: "Is there any so I can get that javascript is completed ?" - No. There's no solution in general. Some support from flash code is required.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with stratton and kirilloid. but if you cannot change the flash source, you could try to add time breaks in javascript like

```
// app is generating flash chart..
var generatedFlashChart = yourWayToGenerateIt();    

setTimeout ( 
     function(){
          makingImageOf( generatedFlashChart ); 
     }, 5000 ); // 5000 = 5seconds
```

so after 5000ms the app will call your function to generate a picture of your flash chart. not  a good solution, but only way in my eyes if you cannot access your flash sources

Comment: already tried but it's not a solution. It's not sure that in specified time interval flash will be completed